# can we use a dictionary element to call a function? or just use a dictionary to call it?

Tags: python

i'm trying to make a module where we have different dictionaries and one function to compute the value of a key common to each dictionary.

i've just tried it on IDLE but there is a syntax error.

```
p3={'name':'Bhuvneshwar Kumar', 'role':'bowl', 'wkts':1, 'overs':10,'runs':71, 'field':1} 
p4={'name':'Yuzvendra Chahal', 'role':'bowl', 'wkts':2, 'overs':10, 'runs':45, 'field':0} 
p5={'name':'Kuldeep Yadav', 'role':'bowl', 'wkts':3, 'overs':10, 'runs':34, 'field':0}

def fieldfun(player):
    fpoint=0
    if field>0:
        fpoint==10
        print("player gets points for fielding")
    else:
        print("No points for fielding!")

fieldfun(p3)
```

i should have a list of all the dictionaries where field got points, and if not then i should get no points but instead i'm getting ->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/sem 3/PYTHON/field.py", line 15, in <module>
    fieldfun(p1)
  File "F:/sem 3/PYTHON/field.py", line 9, in fieldfun
    if field>0:
NameError: name 'field' is not defined
```

Comment: in the local scope of the function there is no notion of just `field` it's not a defined variable, but perhaps `player.get('field')` might help? you should be able to figure it out from there

Comment: What is point of line `fpoint==10`? You are asking is `fpoint` equal to `10`, but do no use that information.

Comment: @Daweo this is just part of the module. fpoint is going to be used later

Comment: @aws_apprentice so i shouldn't mention field as an attribute? and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since player is dictionary , you cant not assess dictionary element directly by writing key values . all you have to do either use `<dict_name>.get('<field_name>')` or `<dict_name>['<key_name'>]`

```
p3={'name':'Bhuvneshwar Kumar', 'role':'bowl', 'wkts':1, 'overs':10,'runs':71, 'field':1} 
p4={'name':'Yuzvendra Chahal', 'role':'bowl', 'wkts':2, 'overs':10, 'runs':45, 'field':0} 
p5={'name':'Kuldeep Yadav', 'role':'bowl', 'wkts':3, 'overs':10, 'runs':34, 'field':0}

def fieldfun(player):
    fpoint=0
    if player.get('field')>0:
        fpoint==10
        print("player gets points for fielding")
    else:
        print("No points for fielding!")

fieldfun(p3)
```

## output

```
player gets points for fielding
```